# regular covers for spaces with abelian fundamental group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

An old exam question I found asks

"Let $p:\bar{X}\rightarrow X $ be a covering map, such that $\bar{X}$ is path connected and $\pi_1(X)$ is abelian. Are all covering maps regular covering maps"

Definitions:

$p$ is a covering map, if it is surjective and locally trivializing

$p$ is a regular covering map, if the deck transformation group $\Delta(p)$ acts transitively on the fiber. We **don't** assume $X$ (or $\bar{X}$) to be locally path connected.

I got a proof if $X$ is locally path connected (using lifts), but how would I prove it without that condition? (Or is there a counterexample?)

Comment: If $\bar X$ is path connected and $p:\bar X\to X$ is continuous and surjective, then $X$ is also path connected.

Comment: @Berci: path connected does not imply locally path connected (if this is what you mean)

Comment: "Are all covering maps normal covering maps": I guess you want to ask whether the given $p$ is a regular covering.

Comment: I doubt that it is true without the assumption that $X$ is locally path connected. Each deck transformation is a lift of $p$, and the existence of a lift cannot be proved without certain assumptions on $X$. In the locally connected category it is known that $p$ is regular if and only if $p_\ast(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}))$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(X,x)$  for all / some $\tilde{x}  \in p^{-1}(x)$ which answers your question for abelian fundamental group.

Comment: If $p$ is a two-sheeted covering, then it is regular without any further assumptions. The map exchanging the two points in any fiber is easily seen to be continuous. Hence it is a deck transformation.